# Is there any way to use a touch screen monitor to CONTROL an Android tablet through USB?

Tags: touchscreen, usb-peripherals

I have a Coby MID7065 Android tablet that I want to connect to a 4 wire capacitive touch screen monitor via USB. I want to be able to control my tablet via the touch screen monitor. I need to know if there is a way to do this, or if drivers that must be written for the Android OS to make this work or where I can get this information.

Comment: Do you have a link / picture of "4 wire capacitive touch screen monitor via USB", with the device and wires? I can't imagine what that looks like. Interesting problem / question though.

Comment: No i don't. A 4 wire capacitive touch screen is a type of touch screen. There is also a 4 wire resistance touch, projection capacitive, and infrared as well. The last two people are most familiar with because tablets and smart phones use these technologies for their touch screens which also allows for multi touch applications.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no Android devices ship with drivers for a USB touchscreen monitor. To make this work, you'd have to find or write drivers for Android, and they'd probably be specific to the type of monitor.

In the first instance you could approach the monitor manufacturer and see if they know of a driver for Android, or are willing to give you the datasheets you'd need to write one.

Comment: There's no need to comment to say thank-you. If the answer helped you, accept it using the green tick/check mark on the left. That's our way of saying thank-you. You get some reputation for doing this too!